# java - synchronization and volatile variable

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, volatile, java-memory-model

I've read from [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html) that:

> ...Synchronized blocks also guarantee that all variables accessed inside the synchronized block will be read in from main memory, and when the thread exits the synchronized block, all updated variables will be flushed back to main memory again, **regardless of** whether the variable is declared `volatile` or not.

There's also an example showed in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997):

```java
public class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;
    
    private static synchronized void requestStop() {
        stopRequested = true;
    }
    
    private static synchronized boolean stopRequested() {
        return stopRequested;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequested()) i++
        });
        backgroundThread.start();
        
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        requestStop();
    }
}
```

The variable `stopRequested` is not declared as `volatile` and the author states that "...In other words, the synchronization on these methods is used solely for its **communication effects**, not for mutual exclusion...". But I would like to know that, in case of accessing an element of an array or accessing a field of an object in a `synchronized` method/block, could we always guarantee the memory visibility, **without** having to manually force a volatile access of the array's element (by using `Unsafe#getObjectVolatile` for example) or declare the `volatile` modifier on the object's field? Thanks!

```java
// flags is an instance of a custom class. Should Flags.stopRequested be declared volatile?
public class StopThread {
    private static Flags flags = new Flags(); 
    
    private static synchronized void requestStop() {
        flags.stopRequested = true;
    }
    
    private static synchronized boolean stopRequested() {
        return flags.stopRequested;
    }
}
```

```java
// flags is an array. Should we use getObjectVolatile/putObjectVolatile to access the element?
public class StopThread {
    private static boolean[] flags = new boolean[n]; 
    
    private static synchronized void requestStop() {
        flags[m] = true;
    }
    
    private static synchronized boolean stopRequested() {
        return flags[m];
    }
}
```

Comment: Re, "Synchronized blocks...guarantee that all variables...will be read in from main memory, and...all updated variables will be flushed back to main memory" That certainly is one possible implementation, but the actual guarantee is more general than that. You can sum it up this way: The Java Language Spec guarantees that whatever one thread does to shared variables before it leaves a synchronized block will become visible to any other thread that subsequently enters a block that is synchronized on the same lock object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, flags is initialised using a `static` initialiser. It is guaranteed by the Java Memory Model that any subsequent reads would see the updated value of the reference, and the correct initial state of `Flags` (basically, `Flags` would be properly published).

However, since `Flags` is mutable and might be mutated at a later point in time by multiple threads, you need to use proper synchronisation to ensure memory visibility for its state. So a `volatile` would be needed for its fields (or proper synchronisation).

In the second example, simply declaring `flags` as `volatile` won't ensure memory visibility of writes to arrays. It just ensures a *happens-before* relationship b/w writes to the array reference and subsequent reads from it. To ensure a *happens-before* relationship b/w writes to array elements and subsequent reads from them, you need to use locking, which you are already doing.

Why this works? The JMM guarantees a *happens-before* relationship b/w the release of a monitor and its re-acquisition. When a thread releases a lock which is later acquired by another thread, a kind-of total ordering (governed by *happens-before*) is ensured b/w whatever writes happened in the previous thread and any subsequent reads by the thread that re-acquired the lock.

Just remember that declaring a reference as `volatile` does not ensure proper visibility of the mutable state of the object it refers to. We still need proper synchronisation mechanisms to ensure memory visibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So in my understanding if the `flags` in the two examples could only be accessed by the two `synchronized` method (`requestStop` and `stopRequested`), there will be no need to declare `Flags.stopRequested` or `boolean[] flags` as `volatile`, nor to use `getObjectVolatile` or `putObjectVolatile` to access the array, because `synchronized` keyword has already guarantee the happens-before relationship between threads. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, no need to use volatile. volatile anyway is a much weaker primitive to proper synchronisation, and you have used proper synchronisation already.